# Tomcat home directory environment variable

Tags: tomcat, tomcat10

I'm currently editing the server.xml context paths and want to have a context path back to the original webapps directory. Is there an built in tomcat environment variable that points back to the tomcat installation directory like TOMCAT_HOME or something?

Comment: The environment variables [`CATALINA_HOME` and `CATALINA_BASE`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/introduction.html#CATALINA_HOME_and_CATALINA_BASE) can be accessed through `${catalina.home}` and `${catalina.base}` in `server.xml`. However most paths are already relative to `CATALINA_BASE`. Can you explain better what you want to achieve? It seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/930241), maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: Well I changed my <Host name="localhost"  appBase="C:/FB20/web/", so when i set context paths, they seem to be relative to that. But since the manager and other default apps are still in the webapps folder, I want to have a context path set up to access those. When I add <Context path="/manager" docBase="/webapps"/> the log file stderror says it can't find C:\FB20\web\webapps. So basically I want to change that to TOMCAT_HOME/webapps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the Tomcat installation directory is available as `${catalina.home}` property, while the Tomcat instance root directory through `${catalina.base}` (cf. [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/introduction.html#CATALINA_HOME_and_CATALINA_BASE)). E.g. you can use `${catalina.home}/webapps/manager` for the location of the Tomcat Manager application.

However I wouldn't define the contexts for Tomcat Manager and other applications in `server.xml`: they have their own context definitions in the `META-INF/context.xml` file of their folder, so they probably should not be redefined in `server.xml`: this way you can loose some important configuration attributes (like `privileged="true"` for Tomcat Manager).

A better solution would be to copy those definitions into `conf/Catalina/localhost/<appname>.xml` and add the `docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/<appname>` attribute. E.g. for Tomcat Manager you should create a file named `conf/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml` with content:

```xml
<Context docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/manager" antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
  <CookieProcessor className="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor"
                   sameSiteCookies="strict" />
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
  <Manager sessionAttributeValueClassNameFilter="java\.lang\.(?:Boolean|Integer|Long|Number|String)|org\.apache\.catalina\.filters\.CsrfPreventionFilter\$LruCache(?:\$1)?|java\.util\.(?:Linked)?HashMap"/>
</Context>
```